# Dynamic JPA query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities Questions and UserAnswers. I need to make an api in spring boot which returns all the columns from both the entities based on some conditions.

Conditions are:

1. I will be give a comparator eg: >, <, =, >=, <=
2. A column name eg: last_answered_at, last_seen_at
3. A value of the above column eg: 28-09-2020 06:00:18

I will need to return an inner join of the two entities and filter based on the above conditions.

Sample sql query based on above conditions will be like:

```
SELECT q,ua from questions q INNER JOIN 
user_answers ua on q.id = ua.question_id 
WHERE ua.last_answered_at > 28-09-2020 06:00:18
```

The problem I am facing is that the column name and the comparator for the query needs to be dynamic.

Is there an efficient way to do this using spring boot and JPA as I do not want to make jpa query methods for all possible combinations of columns and operators as it can be a very large number and there will be extensive use of if else?

Comment: have you check: https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/specifications.html#:~:text=Spring%20Data%20provides%20Specification%20interface,to%20execute%20JPA%20criteria%20queries.&text=That%20means%20we%20only%20have,provided%20to%20us%20by%20Spring.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a clear custom implementation of a repository method. Firstly, I will make some assumptions about the implementation of your entities. Afterwards, I will present an idea on how to solve your challenge.

I assume that the entities look basically like this (getters, setters, equals, hachCode... ignored).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "questions")
public class Question {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime lastAnsweredAt;

    private LocalDateTime lastSeenAt;

    // other attributes you mentioned...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<UserAnswer> userAnswers = new ArrayList();

    // Add and remove methods added to keep bidirectional relationship synchronised
    public void addUserAnswer(UserAnswer userAnswer) {
        userAnswers.add(userAnswer);
        userAnswer.setQuestion(this);
    }

    public void removeUserAnswer(UserAnswer userAnswer) {
        userAnswers.remove(userAnswer);
        userAnswer.setQuestion(null);
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answers")
public class UserAnswer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "task_release_id")
    private Question question;
}
```

I will write the code with the knowledge about the JPA of Hibernate. For other JPAs, it might work similarly or the same.

Hibernate often needs the name of attributes as a `String`. To circumvent the issue of undetected mistakes (especially when refactoring), I suggest the module `hibernate-jpamodelgen` (see the class names suffixed with an underscore). You can also use it to pass the names of the attributes as arguments to your repository method.

Repository methods try to communicate with the database. In JPA, there are different ways of implementing database requests: JPQL as a query language and the Criteria API (easier to refactor, less error prone). As I am a fan of the Criteria API, I will use the Criteria API together with the modelgen to tell the ORM Hibernate to talk to the database to retrieve the relevant objects.

```
public class QuestionRepositoryCustomImpl implements QuestionRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    public List<Question> dynamicFind(String comparator, String attribute, String value) {

        CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<Question> cq = cb.createQuery(Question.class);
        // Root gets constructed for first, main class in the request (see return of method)
        Root<Question> root = cq.from(Question.class);
        // Join happens based on respective attribute within root
        root.join(Question_.USER_ANSWER);

        // The following ifs are not the nicest solution.
        // The ifs check what comparator String contains and adds respective where clause to query
        // This .where() is like WHERE in SQL
        if("==".equals(comparator)) {
            cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(attribute), value));
        }
        if(">".equals(comparator)) {
            cq.where(cb.gt(root.get(attribute), value));
        }
        if(">=".equals(comparator)) {
            cq.where(cb.ge(root.get(attribute), value));
        }
        if("<".equals(comparator)) {
            cq.where(cb.lt(root.get(attribute), value));
        }
        if("<=".equals(comparator)) {
            cq.where(cb.le(root.get(attribute), value));
        }

        // Finally, query gets created and result collected and returned as List
        // Hint for READ_ONLY is added as lists are often just for read and performance is better.
        return entityManager.createQuery(cq).setHint(QueryHints.READ_ONLY, true).getResultList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was getting syntax error in this part: Join<Question, UserAnswer> join= root.join(Question_.USER_ANSWER. And even if this ran my other problem would be that I have a condition based on which I have to take left join or inner join and I need both the entities question and answer to be returned by my query. I have completed the implementation using custom repository, entity manager and string based query implementation.

Comment: @anuragbnrj Do you use `hibernate-jpamodelgen` correctly? Can you probably post a more detailed description of your syntax error (stack trace)? You can also just use the field names as a String. The repository method returns a `List<Question>`. Each question includes already the associated `List<UserAnswer>`. An ORM like Hibernate translates the database scheme automatically into objects.

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a library called [spring-dynamic-jpa](https://github.com/joutvhu/spring-dynamic-jpa) to make it easier to implement dynamic queries with JPA.

You can use it to write the query templates. The query template will be built into different query strings before execution depending on your parameters when you invoke the method.

Comment: Thanks, will have a look at it. I have completed the implementation using custom repository, entity manager and string based query implementation.